# MPI only compiles in Visual Studio debug section

Tags: c++, windows, terminal, compiler-errors, mpi

I have this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    printf("Hello, World!");
    cout << MPI_Comm_rank << " " << MPI_Comm_size << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug this in Microsoft Visual Studios it works just fine. But when I try it in the command prompt or any terminal I get this error,

```
Project_1.cpp:2:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <mpi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have g++ installed already and it works with other programs just fine. I have MPI installed too. Was able to link it to my Microsoft Visual Studio but it only works in its debug section. I am using a windows computer. Not really sure what to do. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: You have added the include path to Microsoft Visual Studio's debug settings - you need to same information in the release configuration and any command prompt session.

Comment: Your `cout` statement contains two function names. I'm surprised that this would work, and it certainly doesn't give the output you are expecting.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout: the name of a function will evaluate to the function's address. At a guess, that's getting converted to `void *` to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem with your program:

- You don't define `MPI_Comm_rank` and  `MPI_Comm_size` but you try to print them in `cout`. In the following piece of code, I've rewritten your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    printf("Hello, World!");
    cout << rank << " " << size << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

- You also need to add the location of `mpiexec.exe` to your system PATH by :

  1- Open `Window’s System Properties` dialog box => click on `Environment Variables`

  2- Click `edit` for the Path variable => add `C: Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin \` (Assuming the default install)
- To include the appropriate libraries.

  1- The MPI code should be compiled as a Console Application

  2- Once you have created the project you need to add the appropriate library

  - Right-click on the project in the `Solution Explorer` and go to `Properties`
  - Click on `VC++ Directories` and (assuming the MPI SDK is installed in the default directory) add:

    - `C:/ Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Include` to the Include Directories
    - `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Lib/x64` or `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Lib/x86` to the Library Directories
    - Depends on whether you wish to compile your code as 32bit or 64bit

  3- Click on Linker =>Input

  - Under Additional Dependencies add `msmpi.lib`

Comment: I get the exact same error when I do this. For some reason it still doesn't recognize <mpi.h> on the terminal but will on the debugger. I also can't seem to find mpiexec.exe file anywhere on my computer. Is it possible that it didn't download with the rest of MPI? I am having a lot of trouble with this for some reason.

Comment: I recommend you download it again. Maybe you haven't downloaded it properly. You need to install Microsoft MPI:
• https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/microsoft-mpi
• Click on Downloads and download and install both “msmpisdk.msi” and
“msmpisetup.

Comment: Just did that and same problem arises. There also doesn't seem to be Microsoft MPI folder in program files, but the Microsoft SDKs are in Program files (x86).

Comment: The Microsoft MPI should be in ```program files``` and Microsoft SDKs are in ```Program files (x86)```.